# Error in stored procedure, but where?

Tags: sql

Below is a stored procedure for deleting an invoice. An invoice contains of one or more invoice lines, and an invoice line contains of on or more of an article.

Here's how it works:

1. The number of articles on the invoice lines is updated in the articles table (quantity).
2. The invoice lines are deleted
3. The invoice is deleted

The following tables are affected:

- INVOICE - Contains InvoiceID, Date, Paymentterms and CustomerID (fk) <---------- contains of a invoice with InvoiceID 8
- INVOICELINE - Contains InvoicelineID, InvoiceID (fk), ArticleID (fk), Quantity, Price and Discount
- ARTICLE - Contains articles with Articlename, Quantity, Price and Discount.

Below is the SP, but by some strange reason I get an error when running it (the invoice i'm trying to delete does of course exists). Can someone see what's wrong with it?

Thanks in advance!

```
ALTER PROCEDURE usp_DeleteInvoice
@InvoiceID int
AS
BEGIN
  BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRANSACTION;

    WITH fr AS (
      SELECT ArticleID, SUM(Quantity) AS ReclaimedQuantity
      FROM Invoiceline
      WHERE InvoiceID = @InvoiceID
      GROUP BY ArticleID
    )

    UPDATE Article
    SET Quantity = Quantity + fr.ReclaimedQuantity
    FROM Article INNER JOIN
         fr ON Article.ArticleID = fr.ArticleID;

    DELETE FROM Invoiceline
    WHERE InvoiceID = @InvoiceID;

    DELETE FROM Invoice
    WHERE InvoiceID = @InvoiceID; <- Error here

    COMMIT TRANSACTION;
  END TRY

  BEGIN CATCH
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    RAISERROR ('Couldn't delete invoice!',16,1)
  END CATCH
END
GO

EXEC usp_DeleteInvoice 8
```

EDIT:
I get the following error message (line 36 = WHERE InvoiceID = @InvoiceID;):

- Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Here's the structure of the invoice table (the numbers from one of the invoices that exists):

- Invoice ID (PK, int): 7
- Date (date): 2011-01-01
- Paymentterms (tinyint) 30
- CustomerID: 1

Comment: What type of error are you getting?  I know your try/catch blocks will prevent you from seeing it, so you may want to try running it without those blocks to get the full error message.

Comment: So all that detail about what the stored procedure does but not one word about what actually goes wrong?

Comment: @Jason what is the structure of your Invoice table? also what is the error thrown when you try and run it?

Comment: Sorry, I've added the message as well as the structure of the invoice table.

Comment: Like TimothyAWiseman said, remove the TRY-CATCH code and run the stored proc again so we can see the real error message.

Comment: Your code looks fine. Are there any triggers or foreign keys that can be preventing the deletion?

Comment: No, not that I can see. Very strange :/

Comment: You don't have any sub-queries in that proc... so that error message makes no sense.  You must have some type of trigger or check constraint that is throwing that error.

Comment: @MichaelFredrickson: You are probably right! I recently created a trigger, so that must be the case. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for a trigger that is incorrectly written to handle only one record at a time.